# Display the value of objective function for infeasible solutions

Tags: java, python, cplex, opl

I have a flow control loop where I want to print/display the value of my objective function even when the solution is not optimal. The flow control loop is attached:

```
main { 
var source = new IloOplModelSource("Proposed.mod");
var cplex = new IloCplex();
var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
var data = new IloOplDataSource("Proposed.dat");

for(var sheet in thisOplModel.sheets){

  var data0=new IloOplDataElements();
  data0.linksread=sheet+"!B2:E22";
  
  var data1=new IloOplDataElements();
  data1.supdemread=sheet+"!I2:I19";
    
  var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
  opl.addDataSource(data0);
  opl.addDataSource(data1);
  
  opl.addDataSource(data);
  opl.generate();

      if (cplex.solve()) {
         opl.postProcess();
      } else {
         writeln(opl.TotalPower);
      }


  opl.end();
}  

data.end(); 
def.end(); 
cplex.end(); 
source.end();

}
```

For the command

```
writeln(opl.TotalPower);
```

I get output as

```
[a IloNumExpr]
```

Is there a way to access the value of "a" or "IloNumExpr"?
Or is there any other way to print the value of the objective function for non-feasible solutions in CPLEX?

Answer (score 0):

You can call relax and then get the value of the expression.

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40 in 0..3;
dvar int+ nbBus30 in 0..3;

dexpr float cost=costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
minimize
 cost;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

main
{
  
 thisOplModel.generate();
 cplex.solve();
 writeln("cost = ",thisOplModel.cost);
 writeln(thisOplModel.printRelaxation());
 writeln("cost = ",thisOplModel.cost);
}
```

gives

```
cost = [a IloNumExpr]
nbBus40 at 5:1-27 C:\poc\algomine2\RCPSP.mod
    relax [0,3] to [0,6] value is 0

cost = 4200
```